# How can i make blender more comfortable, as the handling is very alien to me?

Tags: 3d-view

I have rephrased my question.

How can i change the short-cuts and the handling in "templates", like "Netbeans" does, when you can select "Eclipse"?

The handling of the system is very alien from any windows or linux based non-modelling software also (Google map, photo editor like gimp), not just from existing 3D modelling tools.

Middle button usage for screen rotation (zoom in needs other fancy stuff while rotating as it holds the middle wheel button), 3D cursor holds the whole left button, which is not that important. Right clicks is not throwing me any popup menu, i need to know the particular short-cut keys for that.

A first time beginner looks at the software and recoils, when he just don't get "any responsiveness", trying to click on the crazy way on the left button, and says "what the heck".

i have looked at some webpage which have been generated by blend4web, and interestingly the sites itself worked in the same way, what i have expected how Blender must work,

I would like to see similar behavior like the example sites are working.

Comment: Hi. I suggest reducing the information in your question to just the *relevant* pieces of information. The core of your question seems to be "I would like to change the shortcuts of some tools", but that may get lost in the information regarding your learning of blender (which I would say is not relevant to the question).

Comment: I learned by making a look up table of all the shortcuts keys, and asking here many many times how things are done. There are things in Blender you say so much simpler than Maya's way and way less annoying, in other aspects you think Maya can do this why can't Blender?

Comment: First you need to stop comparing it with Max because it is the different workflow what makes Blender that good (for me). If you start to try make Blender behave / look like Max, it won't serve you well. Just complete some basic tutorial, try to remember basic shortcuts, find what can you do with 3D cursor.. and I am sure the most of things you don't like at this moment will start to make sense for you.
And just a hint - you can always hit Spacebar, type what you want to do and will find your function together with the shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the mouse buttons are bothering you, there is an option to switch the mouse button that you select with (go to User Preferences > Input then change "Select With" to left).

Comment: I have figured out at the end of the day, just i didn't dare to change yet fearing to screw up the system.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a cube, and wanting to move it vertically by 5 units. In blender, there are two ways of doing this.

1. Keyboard: <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>5</kbd>.
2. Mouse: Click the blue arrow, hold down <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while dragging it upwards and count how many clicks it goes through, releasing the mouse when you get to 5.

The second way it easier to learn: you click/drag on the arrows, but if you are using blender for multiple hours per day, using the first method is far superior. As a result, those who make tutorials will often teach methods heavy in keyboard shortcuts - because this is what they use, and it's easier to say "Press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>5</kbd>" than to show clicking/dragging an arrow.

The other thing you need to know about blender's interface is that it follows the rule of "No Dialogs." This is different to most other software, and it means that blender does not 'get in your way' by placing windows over the top of the thing you are working on. As a result, most functionality is visible straight off, and it leads to the 'shotgun of buttons' effect. However, once you have learned how blender manipulates data (eg difference between mesh and object data) you'll find the layout is actually quite intuitive. Again, yes, it requires learning.

I will admit to being unsure of why the mouse buttons are done the way they are, but I don't see any better layout either. Even Real Time Strategy computer games can't decide if it's left or right click to select.....

---

The keyboard shortcuts that are useful/essential to know are:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> (edit mode/object mode)
- <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (grab, rotate, scale) combine with <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> and maybe <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>
- <kbd>E</kbd> (extrude in edit mode)
- <kbd>W</kbd> (subdivide in edit mode)
- <kbd>F</kbd> (Make a face in edit mode)
- <kbd>X</kbd> (delete, but under your finger as opposed to miles away)
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (duplicate, not linking mesh data)
- <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> (toggle side panels)
- <kbd>Z</kbd> (toggle wireframe and solid shading mode. Combine with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> for other modes)
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (undo)
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (redo)

Other useful buttons

- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (edge slide in edit mode)
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Ring cut in edit mode)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (duplicate, linking mesh data)
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (group objects)

Comment: If you put <kbd>Key</kbd> around your shortcuts, it will look a lot better in a post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although my question was not that straightforward, but somebody got the point. Your one is very helpful, only one stuff is missing, how i can zoom and rotate the screen at the same time in a slippy way (not by +/-), if my middle mouse button holds the wheel? The no dialog window didn't cause any headache, as i'm developing for mobiles, i'm not creating dialogs either.:)

Comment: Zoom and rotate? I just don't do them at the same time, and never really considered that it would be useful. I can't think of an easy way, unless you enable 'emulate 3-button mouse', and use alt+click to rotate the view. Then you can use the mouse wheel as normal.